# WEKA - Get InfoGainAttribute selection output using command line

Tags: command-line, weka, feature-selection

When I use the Weka Explorer to Select Attributes with InfoGainAttribute evaluator, I get all featured ranked in the **Attribute selection output** panel

[image: Weka Explorer]

But I need now to do the same operation with the command line. The problem is that I don'nt know how to get the **Attribute selection output** with the command line

This is my command line:

```
java -classpath weka.jar weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -E weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1" -i input.arff -o output.arff
```

The result of this operation is the `output.arff` file, with the same content that `input.arff` file.

I need the Ranked Attributes.

Answer (score 1):

When you look into the Explorer's log (click on button in bottom right corner), you will see something like this in the output:

```
12:13:46: Started weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval
12:13:46: Command: weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval -s "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1"
12:13:46: Filter command: weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -E "weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval " -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1"
12:13:46: Meta-classifier command: weka.classifiers.meta.AttributeSelectedClassifier -E "weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval " -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1" -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -- -C 0.25 -M 2
12:13:46: Finished weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval weka.attributeSelection.Ranker
```

If you want to get the output from the Explorer, you use **Command**, if you want to filter your data, you use **Filter command** and when you want to train a classifier, you use **Meta-classifier command**.

In your case, the command therefore would something like this (**no output file!**):

```
java -classpath weka.jar weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval -s "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1" -i input.arff
```

That you received the same data in `output.arff` as you used as input via `input.arff` is expected, as the `Ranker` only ranks the attributes, but doesn't actually modify the data itself.

**Rule of thumb:** *SubsetEval* schemes will modify the dataset, *AttributeEval* schemes can be used for ranking.